# I have five pending suggested edits, and so I can't submit more. If you have 2k rep, could you please help to process the suggested-edits queue?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits, review

Stack Exchange has a limit of five pending suggested edits per user. This is to prevent users from flooding the suggested-edits queue with tiny edits (e.g. adding a tag) to dozens of questions.

I have [five pending suggested edits](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/33123/unforgettableidsupportsmonica?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), and so I can't submit any more. Mine aren't tiny edits; they're more substantial.

In fact, I've had five pending suggested edits for most of the past week.

## My question

A) If you have 2,000 reputation or more, could you please help to [process the suggested-edits queue](https://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits)?

## An additional thought

B) Perhaps it might make sense to raise the limit to 10 or 20 pending suggested edits, to make the limit more difficult to hit on smaller Stack Exchange sites like ours.

Comment: Feature request on MSE: [Please make the red dot visible also if there are pending reviews near timeout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326355/please-make-the-red-dot-visible-also-if-there-are-pending-reviews-near-timeout). Got +12/-2, no visible reactions.

Comment: [This is a problem since early 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/1360777/median-and-average-decision-times-of-suggested-edits-in-hours-by-month#graph). I think we need far more 2k+ users, alternatively the site (at least the rep limits) could temporarily go back to beta.

Answer (score -2):

All of my pending suggested edits have been processed now. I thank everyone who helped to process the queue!

Comment: It is because sometimes brave mods go over the queue and process it. Thanks, @AndrewT. But not this is the ordinary working of a healthy site, it is a workaround and not a solution. We would need far more active reviewers.